# is this network structure viable?

Tags: networking, routing, load-balancing, switch

[image]

I would like to know if this network structure it would be viable or not.

The main reason it would be to be able to switch manually, the ISP. If one is going down than use the other one.

as I know public web hosting aren't made to his structure. Eg www.mycompany.com has a dedicated hosting plan somewhere in cloud.
At workstations are PC for developers, somewhere it is a Wi-Fi network too for cellphones.

Is there any software, which are doing the automated switching from ISP1 to ISP2 automatically?

Probably I haven't used the networking terms correctly, because lack of deep knowledge, what are the keywords for search?

Comment: I would highly suggest not using a PC for this. Use a dedicated bit of hardware that is meant for the job.

Comment: Because I am a home user at office I am working at workstationX. I had no idea of dedicated hardware for this. I know if there is a PC, than there is an OS which can run my code => if doesn't exist already a software to make that switching in worse case  I can make it. But as I can see if  I believe something is a good idea, than others are using that solution ages :) Thanks for all who has helped with answers, comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most enterprise firewalls will support what you are trying to do and we use Dell Sonicwall which certainly does.

If you are trying to "roll your own" then something link pfSense may do the trick and a quick look at their docs does show that it support multiple WAN links - see https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN_2.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you want to put that level of trust into a PC which is not designed to be "on" 24/7, or even just office hours. What happens if that PC has a software/hardware problem? Means that you will have no internet connectivity for the rest of the office.

There are many routers that support this configuration, and even if you don't have the budget- why not just have 2 routers setup in the same way, but to different ISPs. If one of the ISPs goes down, physically switch the connection?

Comment: +1 for effort, also good point,  I am one of those who are at WorkstationX and screaming when no internet connection again. Need to call the system administrator to make a switching do a reset. This isn't a good idea for us.

Answer (score 1):

Viable, possibly. There's a lot to look at on that dedicated PC. In general, you're going to want a dedicated piece of hardware to be your router rather than a PC, if for no other reason to reduce the visible attack surface on an internet facing device. A support contract to handle the hardware on the single point of failure wouldn't be a bad idea, either. :)

The usual suspects in router or firewall hardware should be able to provide what you need. Be sure to mention load-balancing when you ask, or you may end up with a simple failover solution on the router/firewall. Not that that's necessarily a bad thing.